# yii project , inside another yii project?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I have project with structure like:

```
/var/www/html/
             /protected
             /yii
             /.htaccess
             ...
            /assets
            /secondProject 
                           /proetected
                           /.htaccess
                           ....
                           /assests
```

**secondProject is not working** , when  I call controller action from secondProject , I got:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
   <html><head>
   <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
     <h1>Not Found</h1>
     <p>The requested URL /call/index.php was not found on this server.</p> 
   </body></html>
```

**.htaccess of secondProject is**

```
     RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /secondProject
    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

**and .htaccess inside html folder  is:**

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /secondProject
   # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   # otherwise forward it to index.php
   RewriteRule . index.php
```

**What should I have to change to make it work??** thanks

Comment: Why you need nested projects? You always can use modules for separate C/M/V parts.

Comment: @Justinas I want that my one project work like www.xyz.com and secondproject www.xyz.com/secondproject. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this before the rules in the `.htaccess` file in the root project

```
RewriteRule ^(secondProject)($|/) - [L]
```